# How do I open a file in binary/plaintext format on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, plaintext

This is the thing bugging me. I'd like to see some of my files in binary or plaintext format, but I can't figure out how to do it for all files. I can open some image files in plaintext using Textedit, but that's all I can figure out. Anyone know anything?

Answer (score 18):

Use "`od -h filename | less`" in your Terminal.app.

Comment: I like that I don't have to learn emacs or download a new app with this answer -- in my opinion its the most succinct and best time-saver.

Answer (score 7):

To read binary/text file:

```
xxd file.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) (used to be TextWrangler) as a good general purpose plain-text editor.  If you have this in the Dock, you can drag any file on to it and the file will be opened as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Emacs hexl-mode.

In the terminal, type 'emacs' and the name of the file you want to open.  When emacs opens up the file, type option-x hexl-mode.

Answer (score 1):

I use [HexEdit](http://hexedit.sourceforge.net/) for this sort of thing. It can open any file and give you its hex and plaintext representation.

Answer (score 1):

The editor of my choice for these kinds of things is [Smultron](http://tuppis.com/smultron/).

Answer (score 1):

You can always drop into a Terminal shell session, and use `cat` or `hexdump` to view any file as a text or hexadecimal file.

TextEdit will also display plain text files (as will about any other text editor, as noted by others).

Answer (score 0):

**Open the file with TextEdit** - the plain text editor on MacOS - I was surprised it worked after trying for many days, many ways from many sources